# Calculating equidistant points along an oblong shape (two half circles and a rectangle)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, geometry, trigonometry

In relation to a question from [Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172766/calculating-equidistant-points-around-an-ellipse-arc), I'm trying to do the same but with a different shape. Instead of an ellipse, I'm trying to add points around an oblong (two half circles and a rectangle).

2 points should look like this:

[image]

3 points...

[image]

4 points...

[image]

and 9 points:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you facing an issue?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur this is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/y53dgs0f/

Comment: There's nothing in that Fiddle that tries to address the spacing problem, only the display.  What have you done to solve the central problem?